# access forms: How to retain enable/disable options while accessing forms

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form and certain tabs are enabled and disabled according to the options chosen by the user. This works fine. But when I navigate through my forms later, i find that all the options are accessible and the user has to again select the choice to disable/enable the tabs conditionally. How to overcome this?
P.s. I have used the Afterupdate() option to enable and disable tabs conditionally

Comment: I am runnig the code in Access-vba @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: You have to call the code also in the event `On Current`

Comment: @PatrickHonorez what is the argument to be used with `on current`

Comment: `Form_current()` worked! Thanks @PatrickHonorez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the code also in the event `Form_Current`